# Remix - stuck on creation of contract pending

Tags: solidity, remix

I am using Remix in Chrome.

When I click on 'create' my contract gets stuck on 'creation of contract pending'.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's not stuck. Just read the status *"0x1 Transaction mined and execution succeed"*. And as you can see on the right your contract instance has been created and you can use it to invoke your methods.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, your contract has been deployed successfully but if there is a problem stating that creating contract is pending so you can use ctrl+R and then deploy your code again. I hope it will work

Answer (score -1):

To get more information about the contract that was deployed, check the `listen on all transactions` input to the left of the search bar in the terminal.